# Why creating special arrays in NumPy sometimes require inputting tuple and sometimes not?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For instance, if I create an array with ones:

```
E = np.eye(5, 10) 
print(E)

[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The function require `5, 10` as input. However, if I am creating an array with zeros:

```
F = np.zeros((5, 10))
print(F)

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Then I notice that I have to use a tuple `(5, 10)` as an input. Why NumPy is designed like this? When to use tuple, and when not to, is there a rule?

Comment: Have you checked the docs on each function, and specifically the input parameters to each? Therein lies the answer. If you have, then it would help to specify what is confusing you about the docs.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Documentation, history, and to some degree the nature of the parameters.  `eye` is often called with just one number; the second is optional.  `zeros` doesn't have any such assumption; its input is a `shape` tuple.  But `np.random.rand` defies that logic - but its docs blame history.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the documentation to see why.

here is the documentation for [numpy.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html)

Here is the documentation for [numpy.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

short answer is `numpy.eye` returns an **ndarray of shape (N,M)**, it can't have 3 Dimensions or more !

but `numpy.zeros` takes a tuple as input. it can have any shape with any dimensions. like 3 Dimensions or more !

take a look at this example :

```
>>> np.eye(3,3)
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
>>> np.zeros((2,2,2))
array([[[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]]])
>>> np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
array([[[[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]]]])
```